# list + map with Python don't return lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7, design-patterns

I'm testint [Mediator pattern](https://designpatternsgame.com/patterns/mediator) with python but when I test method with lambda I don't know why return `None`

```py
def requestPositions(self):
        return list(map(lambda airplane: airplane.position, self.airplanes))
```

This is all Pattern.

**I miss return onrequestPositions method**

```
class TrafficTower:
    def __init__(self):
        self.airplanes = []

    def requestPositions(self):
        return list(map(lambda airplane: airplane.position, self.airplanes))

class Airplane:
    def __init__(self, position, trafficTower):
        self.position = position
        self.trafficTower = trafficTower
        self.trafficTower.airplanes.append(self)

    def requestPositions(self):
        return self.trafficTower.requestPositions()


def main():
    airplane = Airplane(10, TrafficTower())
    #FIX why don't return list
    print(airplane.requestPositions())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: FWIW, an `Airplane` should probably not be in control of inserting itself into a `TrafficTower`.

Comment: Tagged as [python-2.7] but using print function from python 3?

Comment: Execute same
``` $ python2.7
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print([2])
[2]
>>> print [2]
[2]
>>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def requestPositions(self):
    self.trafficTower.requestPositions()
```

Missing a `return` here.